# Javascript variable returns to original value after i overwrite it

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting local variable in a JavaScript callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368597/setting-local-variable-in-a-javascript-callback-function)

I am having a hard time debugging my script, for I don't know what is happening in my variable.

I tried doing 'console.log' to track what happens, but in surprise, I don't  have any idea why that happens..

This is the situation :

I have this piece of javascript code :

```
tmplReplaceContent : function(json, tmpl, target){ 
    var template = tmpl;
    var regex = new RegExp("some regex");
    ...
    if (!regex.test(tmpl)) {
        $.get(msi.vars.api_url + tmpl + '.tmpl', function(tmplOut){
            console.log("regex check passed!");
            template = tmplOut;
            console.log(template);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("failed regex check");
    }

    console.log(template);
...
```

that first `console.log(template)` produces my desired results

but the second goes back to it's original value :

e.g.

```
tmpl = somevar; // that returns true on if statement
template = tmpl;

console.log(template) // 1st. will return value of somevar
```

What do you think is the remedy, and why does my code fails?

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous**, i.e. your second `console.log(template)` is executed before the `$.get` callback. Why would you have to pass a callback otherwise?

Comment: uhmm, are there any fix?

Comment: No, because technically nothing is wrong. You have to learn how to work properly with callbacks. For example, you can make `tmplReplaceContent` accept a callback itself, which gets executed whenever the function's work is done (either by making an Ajax call or not).

Comment: then how could i get the value I desired then overwrite the value of template?

Comment: ahh, oops yea, I think that'll will work. I'll try.!